# Naming Convention - Argument used to hold the results of a method

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, naming-conventions

The following code is passing an object of type `TList<integer>` to a method `Split`. Within the method a number gets split into single digits which are then added to a list passed into the method as the second parameter.

#### Question:

Is there any naming convention to improve readability of the method or parameter itself to that effect that it is clear the second argument is used as the result of the method.
I tried using named parameters for this purpose, but it seems that this is not supported in Delphi: `Split(arabicNumber, toList:= numbers);`.

#### Code:

```
var
  numbers: TList<integer>;
  arabicNumber: integer;
begin
  numbers := TList<integer>.Create();
  try
    Split(arabicNumber, numbers); // how can I make it clear that numbers is getting filled within the method
    // do something with numbers
    result := ...;
  finally
    numbers.Free();
  end;
end;

procedure TRomanNumeral.Split(const number: integer; list: TList<integer>);
begin
  // iterate over number and add each single digit to list
  list.Add(digit);
end;
```

Comment: Aside: your try finally is broken. Acquire resource **before** try

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I fixed the code.

Comment: The question itself is rather opinion based and so not a valid question here. Its really hard to see where you are stuck. Give your local an appropriate name. Or make it a function and return a dynamic array.

Comment: I'd expect to receive a list of things as output from a subroutine named *Split*. If I saw a newly created empty list passed to such a routine, I'd assume the output would be stored in that list, regardless of the name of the parameter.

Comment: As @RobKennedy says, this looks clear already. (_In spite of the fact that your aren't initialising you input variable `arabicNumber`._) There is no convention, nor have I ever felt the need to have one. The secret to keeping this clear is: keep your methods reasonably short, and you'll easily see where variables are likely to be getting their values/content updated.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but since you are looking for conventions: You can drop the brackets when calling functions without parameters (Create & Free in your example). You might be tempted to write them if you're coming from a different language, and you can certainly do so, but the "Delphi-way" would be to leave them out.

Answer (score 3):

There is no naming convention for container parameters of a procedure that are used to receive data.

However if you want to make that clear simple use of the English language comes to mind.
You can call the parameter: `Outputs` or `Results`.
In your case the name `OutputDigits` comes to mind.

Another solution is to change the procedure into a function:

```
function TRomanNumeral.Split(const Number: integer): TList<integer>;
begin
  Result:= TList<Integer>.Create;
  while more-digits do
    Result.Add(digit);
  end;
end;
```

This function will create the list and use that as output.

Now it's clear what's happening.

```
Numbers:= Split(arabicNumber);
```

If the purpose of `split` is to add numbers to an existing list then you should change the name of the function to make that clear.

```
function TRomanNumeral.AddSplitDigitsToList(number: integer; OutputDigits: TList<Integer>);
```

Adding XMLdoc comments might also help. Now you'll get info when you hover the mouse over the function.

```
///<Summary>
/// Split: splits an integer into Roman numerals  
/// The numerals are generated using Numbers and added into OutputDigits.
///</Summary>
```

Comment: When the function will return a list instance I suggest to name it ˋSplitToListˋ. Best use case would be to return an ˋIEnumerable<Integer>ˋ but a ˋTArray<Integer>ˋ is also fine.

Comment: The danger to this approach is that it's not immediately obvious that the caller is responsible for resource protection.

Comment: Then have the function produce a `TArray<integer>` that will clean up after itself. Surely everyone knows that a TObject derivative like TList needs to be Freed.

Comment: Um no, you're missing the point. It's not about whether an object instance should be Freed, but ***who is responsible*** for that task.